# How to extract value passed in the URL and use it as parameter in Jmeter?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I am using Jmeter for my performance testing and I am stuck at the point where I need to extract the value from the URL and pass it to Jmeter.

Here is the example:

Application requires user to create an order and then submit it on the next page

I am at a point where I can create an order using Jmeter.

In order to create a script to submit an order I have copied the url from the web page as passed it as a GET method '/order/submit/23'. This '23' number changes everytime I create a new order

The issue I am having here is when I run my jmeter script it creates another order with another number which then mismatch with the '/order/submit/23' url I have passed.

Is there any way to extract this number from the HTML code and pass it to Jmeter?

I looked into the HTML code and this number is a part of URL so not sure how I can extract it. Any suggestions please

I am looking for something like /order/submit/${var}

Thanks

Comment: This answer explains the usage of the `RegEx Extractor`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742267/jmeter-get-parameter-from-redirect-url

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you need to extract some value from response. You can do it with two samplers:

- [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
- [RegEx extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

I think xpath extractor more appropriate in your case