# Jmeter - get parameter from redirect URL

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to write performance test.

In a step #1 I'm visiting url: `https://example.com/login?redirect_to=http://somesite.com`

This url redirects me back to `http://somesite.com?ticket=afsgdfasdfasg`

In my JMeter script I need to extract `ticket` parameter and reuse it in a further logic.

Could you please tell me how it can be achieved ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Add PostProcessor => Regular Expression Extractor;
2. That would look like this:
   [image: RegEx]
3. Further reference this variable as ${ticket}

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this ! One small correction to your answer  - instead of "Main sample only"  - "Main sample and sub-samples" must be selected.