# How to send a parameter in jmeter as a variable?

Tags: java, regex, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I'm trying to launch a performance test, but for each time , there an attribute called "QueryID" which is created in the source code of the application.
 [image: First HTTP Request with QueryID]

There  is a multiple http request and for the QueryID, it has the same value.

I tried to detect it in the previous http request (to pass it through regular expression), but it won't show up.

Has anyone idea how i can configure it as a "variable" that it will be filled in each time with his random value from the application?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742267/jmeter-get-parameter-from-redirect-url

combined with https://www.vinsguru.com/jmeter-post-processors-script-language-comparison/

and https://www.guru99.com/processor-in-jmeter.html

Answer (score 1):

Steps to Resolve this:

1. You have already collected QUERYID value using Regular expression extractor. For example You have returned QUERYID in Reference Name field of Regular expression extractor as shown in below Image.

[image]

2. Now Mention ${QUERYID} in value section as shown in below image

[image]

Comment: Yes this is how it worked fine for me, i was struggling to identify the http request that pass the first QueryID value. Thanks! I also used Json extractor but regular expression was perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the `QueryID` is created in the source code of the application, most probably it's created with a [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) function so you basically need to implement the same function using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Once you generate the value you can store it into a JMeter Variable using `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance and you will be able to use it normally later on.